# Automatic login with Instagram API

Tags: ios, api, instagram

I'm developing an app for iOS devices using Instagram API. I registered my application and i got my client ID, client SECRET and i added my website redirect uri for the authentication success or not. In my app the user can login with username and password of Instagram but i'd like to do it automatically. I want to show a button "Login with your Instagram account" and when this button is tapped, if there is Instagram app on the device and the user is logged in, the app automatically gets the access token and the client ID of the user and go! So, user don't have to insert his Instagram nickname and password. How can i do? thanks.

I know that there are many questions about this, but that's not a duplicate question because there are no clearly solutions for this.

Comment: This is not possible, which apps do this?

Comment: No way to do this, you're right

Comment: Any changes on this two years later? (I had to do the normal WebView oAuth2 way, and haven't seen any difference, but I may be wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of login with instagram app is not supported, currently instagram login will not open instagram app to login, it opens the instagram web login in browser, if you have already logged in using the browser then it will show an option to just accept and continue to your app, if not already logged in, user will have to login with username/password

Comment: what if I don't have a password? (I registered with Facebook)